# Update form field from Jquery select change

Tags: jquery, json, forms

I've been reading but can't seem to get a form field to be updated after a JQuery JSON request:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#client").live('change',function(){                       
$.getJSON('client_get_json.php?id=' + $(this).val()  , function(data) {

//$("input[type=text][name=contact_mob]").html(data.contact_mob); <- no good
//$("input[id='contact_mob']").html(data.contact_mob); <- no good
$("#testdiv").html(data.contact_mob);

}); 
});
});
</script>
```

#testdiv upadates fine with the contact_mob data but I can't get the right syntax for updating the field name="contact_mob" id="contact_mob" which I want to repopulate with all the other contact fileds if the user happens to change the contact.

Also any advice on the correct way to do this kind of thing would be welcomed.

All the fileds are populated from PHP when the document first loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `val()` method to set the value of a input field. If the element has a id you can simply use the id selector `#elementId` to select it. Try this.

```
$("#contact_mob").val(data.contact_mob);
```

If the element do not have an id but it has a name then you can use attribute(name) selector like this.

```
$("input[name='contact_mob']").val(data.contact_mob);
```

You can do the same for all the form fields and populate them.

Comment: $("#contact_mob").val(data.contact_mob);
That worked thank you so much. Why does my code work with the #testdiv is what I don't understand?

Comment: Because `#testdiv` is not a form element, it has `innerHTML` property which is what is set when you use jQuery `html()` method. But for form elements you should always use `val()` method to set the values.

Comment: Ok thanks ShankarSangoli, I thought that because it had an ID I could use that to reference it.

Comment: @Peter - It is good now you know, mark is as answer whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

`$('#contact_mob').val(data.contact_mob);`